# More than two states using a StateListDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a requirement where I have to specify a review rating (0 stars to 5 stars) This rating is shown as an `ImageView`. I understand that `StateListDrawable` can be used when there are two states in which a button/view exist (for instance a selected state and an idle state)

My question is if there is a way of including more states (in this case 6 states) and show the drawables accordingly.

Currently I can only do this -

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/zerostars"
          android:state_selected="true" 
          android:background="@color/tab_background_1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fivestars" />
</selector>
```

Any suggestions will be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Level List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: thank you, this fits my current requirements, also just for info, i also found a solution where i created a custom adapter that extends SimpleCursorAdapter and sets the drawable based on each string returned.